# Show value on another page when button click, in php and value stored in database

Tags: php, html, mysql

**I am making a announcement section in Admin page in PHP**. I want to pass directly announcement, through button click to home page in my website. I am using phpmyadmin mysql.

Here are the screen of admin-
[announcement make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Btc8h.png)

```
<?php
            if (isset($_POST['submit_make'])) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM announce_table";
            $result = $con->query($sql);
            }
            ?>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit_make" value="Make"/>
```

This is homepage announcement section where i want to get data from button--
[homepage-where-to-print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykbF5.png)

```
<h4>fresh news</h4>
      <p>
    <!--/here i want to get that announcement when button click/-->
       </p>
```

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. **We can’t run your screenshot as code.**

Comment: I have no idea how to do this i have just added the code from where to where to get data

Answer (score 0):

Based on your information: You have an announcement section to create announcements and then you retrieve all the announcement in you admin section.
after clikcing on "make" announcement you would like to view that announcement in your homepage right? if that's the case:

create a column "status" in your announcement table in your sql. for example:

```
ID | titel | message | status
```

[image]

```
So when you are populating your announcements, create a form
around the "make" button, like this:

<?php foreach($announcements as $announcement){ ?>

 <div>
 <h4><?php echo $announcement.title; ?></h4>
 <p><?php echo $announcement.message; ?></p>
 <form type="post" action="make_announcement.php">
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $announcement.id; ?>" />
 <button type="submit" name="make_announcement">Make</button>
 </form>
 <form type="post" action="delete_announcement.php">
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $announcement.id; ?>" />
 <button type="submit" name="delete_announcement">Make</button> 
 <!-- this is submit to make_announcement.php -->
 </form>

 </div>     ?>
```

then in your make_announcement.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['make_announcement')){

$id = $_POST['id'];
$sql = "UPDATE announcement_table SET status = 1 WHERE id=$id;"; 

//then run the query and update the status.
```

finally in your home page get all announcements where status == 1.